# Can I pass enviroment variable from CircleCI to code in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring, heroku, circleci

I want to put environment variables from CircleCI to application-production.properties file when deploying on Heroku.

application-production.properties

```
jwt.secret-key=${JWT_SECRET_KEY}

registration.url=${REGISTRATION_URL}

spring.mail.host=${MAIL_HOST}
spring.mail.port=${MAIL_PORT}
spring.mail.username=${MAIL_USERNAME}
spring.mail.password=${MAIL_PASSWORD}
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.required=true
```

application.properties (just to make sure I set profile right)

```
spring.profiles.active=production
```

.circleci/config.yml

```
version: 2.1

executors:
  java-version:
    docker:
      - image: 'cimg/openjdk:11.0.7'

orbs:
  maven: circleci/maven@1.0.0
  heroku: circleci/heroku@1.0.1

workflows:
  build_deploy:
    jobs:
      - maven/test:
          executor: java-version
      - heroku/deploy-via-git:
          requires:
            - maven/test
          filters:
            branches:
              only: master
```

Heroku logs:

```
...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'MAIL_HOST' in value "${MAIL_HOST}"
...
```

Did I miss something? What is the best approach to deal with credentials/sensitive data, and working with CI/CD?

It works locally (sending emails) and it pass build and deploy on CircleCI but when starting on Heroku it crash.

Comment: Where do you store the application-production.properties?

Comment: @BeppeC in src/main/resources both application-production.properties and application.properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when deploying on Heroku it is good practise to use [Config Vars](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars) to provide runtime configuration variables.

Make sure the variable names are UPPERCASE and match exactly what you define in the property file.

Comment: Oh man, thanks! I thought that the environment variables are passed to Heroku from CircleCI or placeholders are replaced by value, so when I have e.g. `spring.mail.host=${MAIL_HOST}` I assume that, Heroku searched for such value in Config Vars but I didn't specify any. Is there a way to have just one place to store sensitive data?

Comment: Np! The Config Vars should be the one place (not in the code, not in other files)